# Match any 10-alphanumeric combination between % and %

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that contains various symbols, but I need to get a 10-alphanumeric substring that is located between % and % - but there might be more than one combination of  % and %  in one string

Example: %bla1234bla%, or %12aa22bb33% etc. (I don't need the %)

I tried this:

```
String resultString = Regex.Match(lnk, @"\[%\](.*?)\[%\]{10}").Value;
```

and it does not work

Comment: Is `%bla1234567890%` a valid match?

Comment: %bla1234bla%, or %12aa22bb33% etc.

Comment: "it does not work" : Can you be more specific. What error do you get? What matches when it shouldn't? What doesn't match when it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=%)[\da-zA-Z]{10}(?=%)
```

By looking positive lookahead and lookbehind, this will match the 10 alphanumeric characters between % chars, without actually matching the % chars.

Comment: @gdoron: Why do you think that? Is lookahead/behind expensive or is this just syntactically complicated?

Comment: I don't know about the performance, but it has a complicated syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Try this regular expression:

```
@"%[0-9a-zA-Z]{10}%"
```

Or this:

```
@"%[^\W_]{10}%"
```

> I don't need the %

You can use a capturing group to specify which part you wish to capture:

```
@"%([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})%"
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/FIyuI)

Comment: sorry, I meant letter/number which has length of 10 symbols

Comment: @Andrew. What about uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
@"%[\da-zA-Z]{10}%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if regex is a requirement, but this seems to work...

```
string[] stringArray = testString.Split('%')
                                 .Where(s => s.Length == 10)
                                 .ToArray();
```